# Change Elementary OS Lock Screen Background With Vala and User Specific

Tags: greeter, vala, wallpaper

I've been trying to change the background image of pantheon-greeter. It should change on the depending user. After browsing the [code base of pantheon greeter](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/pantheon-greeter/trunk/view/head:/src/PantheonGreeter.vala) if found that they get the background image from the method `LightDM.User.get_background ()`. Is that the right way? If it is so how can I change the user specific background with Vala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution in the official code of the [elementary settings app](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/master/view/head:/src/Views/Wallpaper.vala).

```
[DBus (name = "org.freedesktop.Accounts.User")]
    interface AccountsServiceUser : Object {
    public abstract void set_background_file (string filename) throws IOError;
}
```

Define Dbus and declare the private member on your class

```
//Instance of the AccountsServices-Interface for this user
private AccountsServiceUser accountsservice = null;
```

and the implementation

```
try {
        string uid = "%d".printf ((int) Posix.getuid ());
        accountsservice = Bus.get_proxy_sync (BusType.SYSTEM,
                "org.freedesktop.Accounts",
                "/org/freedesktop/Accounts/User" + uid);
    } catch (Error e) {
        warning (e.message);
    }
```

is actually what is needed. So you can call

```
accountsservice.set_background_file (path);
```

For more information about the implementation look in the source of the switchboard project of Elementary at launchpad